# Full disk encryption with lvm2 fails after kernel update

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, encryption

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with full disk encryption.

This was implemented as per the guide here:

http://57un.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/full-disk-encryption-using-ubuntu-in-most-secure-mode-with-aes-xts-plain64/

This was working fine until the kernel was upgraded from 3.5.0-32-generic to 3.5.0-34-generic.

Now during boot, the encrypted partition fails to mount and drops into (initramfs) prompt with the following.

```
Gave up waiting for root device.
...
ALERT! /dev/mapper/crypt does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

The system will still boot okay when the previous kernel is selected in GRUB.

I understand that the boot process requires a different step or image to enable lvm2 to mount the encrypted root prior to booting, but am not sure where or how to troubleshoot and correct the problem.

I have tried creating a new initrd

```
    sudo update-initramfs -u
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-34-generic
```

Extract from grub.cfg

Broken:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-34-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f4554fcf-eba8-4cb0-96ea-1427fff02328
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic root=/dev/mapper/crypt ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-34-generic
}
```

Works:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f4554fcf-eba8-4cb0-96ea-1427fff02328
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.0-32-generic root=/dev/mapper/crypt ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-3.5.0-32-generic
}
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that spaces in my `/etc/crypttab` were causing the newly created `initrd` to fail.  Even though the crypttab file appeared okay.

This was discovered after I rolled back to the working kernel and also broke it when I created a new `initrd` using:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I removed the unnecessary spaces from /etc/crypttab and updated the initramfs again.

All good.